# Can a force be induced on an object by firing electromagnetic waves at another object to move it?

Tags: forces, electromagnetic-radiation

Say I could fire some kind of electromagnetic wave which was able to push back another object. To me, it seems that this would also push me away from the object. However, this seems like it should break some kind of laws of physics but I can't think of any way this would not work. All I want to know is if this would work in some way.

Answer (score 2):

You're imagining you "fire off" your wave and then, some random time later, a remote object interacts with it and feels a force. You question is, where's the reaction? Am I right?

If so, I don't think it's any different than if you shoot off a rifle and, some random time later, the bullet hits a tin can and knocks it over. Where's the reaction then? [It's in your sore shoulder when you fired the gun].

So I would say your misconception is that the electromagnetic wave you sent off at the start was reactionless when it left your transmitter - it wasn't. To generate an electromagnetic wave, you need to accelerate a charge. Charges have inertia, so there is a reaction. This reaction is transmitted to the metal that makes up your antenna, causing it to vibrate.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EM wave carries **field momentum**, together with **mechanical momentum** observe the conservation of momentum. So to send an EM wave forward, which carries field momentum forward, you must also generate either some backwards field or other mechanical processes to balance it.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. This is the operating principle of the linear particle accelerator (like SLAC for example), in which a train of electromagnetic waves is used to propel bunches of electrons down the length of the accelerator to higher and higher energies.

Since the masses of the electrons in those bunches is extremely small, the reaction force exerted on the accelerator by the electrons is similarly small.